# call Lua function from C++ conditionally

Tags: c++, function, lua, luabridge

I am using Lua to write scipts and embed them in C++. I use ***LuaBridge*** in this process.

In my Lua script, I have ***some variables which need to be retrieved at first for usage in C++,*** besides, I have a very simple function:

```
run = function()
    print ("state is on!")
end
```

This function, however, is ***only called under a specific condition***. i.e. only called when a "true" is obtained from C++ codes ***after a series of complicated calculations.***

Limited by my Lua and LuaBridge knowledge, what I know is: after I do

```
loadscript(L, "script.lua")
lua_pcall(L,0,0,0)
```

I can read out variables and functions from Lua script by using

```
LuaRef blabla = getGlobal(L, "blabla")
```

But now, I need to read out variables and use them at first, then in a member function

```
LuaRunner::LuaRun(){}
```

defined in a separate C++ class

```
class LuaRunner
```

the condition will be obatined and this run() function will be called if the condition is "true". It would be best to call this run() function right in the C++ member function

```
LuaRunner::LuaRun(){}
```

due to restriction of further processing.

Therefore, I was wondering whether this would be possible:

Read out the function using

```
LuaRef run = getGlobal(L, "run")
```

together with other variables at the beginning and ***"save"*** this run() function somewhere in C++ codes (perhaps as a class member function), and then the run() function can be called later on by a pointer or an object in the same class. Would this be possible? If possible, how to do it? Or any other good ideas?

Comment: Do want to use the lua function "run" as an result callback in a C++ method?

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean by "callback" in a c++ method? I am sorry that I am such a newbie in this area, so could you describe in more details or give me some webpage links?

Comment: A callback is simply a function passed as argument to another function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Comment: @Daniel seems cool, I will learn in details and try, thanks for recommending this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to store **luabridge::LuaRef**'s in C++ to call them later just as you normally call any other function. Though sometimes there's no need to store **LuaRef**'s anywhere. Once you load the script, all functions stay in your **lua_State**, unless you set them to nil or override them by loading another script which uses the same names for functions. You can get them by using **getGlobal** function. If your Lua function takes arguments, you can pass them, using **LuaRef's** operator() like this:

```
if(...) { // your call condition
    LuaRef f = getGlobal(L, "someFunction");
    f(arg1, arg2, ...); // if your function takes no arguments, just use f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if the condition is in a class member function that is far far away from main function (like: main function calls a class member function, then this calls another class member function, and another, and so on, then to the function I am in.....), should I pass the lua state L as a function argument all along?

Comment: Well, you either pass pointer to lua_State or LuaRef itself. Or, you can store LuaRef in the class which uses the function.

Comment: okay..by "store LuaRef in the class which uses the function", do you mean storing LuaRef as a member of the class? Or storing the (for example) LuaRef f = getGlobal(L, "someFunction") in the class which uses the function?

Comment: Yeah, you can store it as a member. (or a static member, to not create unnecessary copies between instances)

Comment: cool..I have nevered stored a class as a member of another class..let me try

Comment: You shouldn't store *class*, you should store an object of class LuaRef